# Laravel 8, Vue3 Redirect the user after login without using vue-router

Tags: php, laravel-8, vuejs3

New in vue.js world!
Try to make a login system in vue.js 3 and using laravel 8.
The problem is dat I do not succeed to redirect the user to the dashboard after the user is logged in. I don't use vue-router. I want to use laravel controller instead of vue-router.

I have tried different ways like this but it does not work

```
this.$router.push('/dashboard');
```

How can I solve the problem?

This is my login vue component

```
<template>
    <form class="text-left offset-top-30" method="post" @submit.prevent="submit()">
        <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="success">Your are logged in. You get redirect to the dashboard</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="errors.failed">
            {{ errors.failed }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text input-group-icon input-group-addon-inverse">
                        <span class="novi-icon mdi mdi-account-outline"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input class="form-control"
                       id="email"
                       placeholder="Your e-mail"
                       type="email"
                       name="email"
                       v-model="fields.email"
                >
                <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors && errors.email">
                    <strong>
                        {{ errors.email[0] }}
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group offset-top-20">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text input-group-icon input-group-addon-inverse">
                        <span class="novi-icon mdi mdi-lock-open-outline"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input class="form-control"
                       id="password"
                       placeholder="Your Password"
                       type="password"
                       name="password"
                       v-model="fields.password"
                >
                <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors && errors.password">
                    <strong>
                        {{ errors.password[0] }}
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-block btn-primary offset-top-20" type="submit">
            Sign In
            <span class="icon novi-icon mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle-outline"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            fields: {},
            success: false,
            errors: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            axios.post('/api/login', this.fields)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.status === 200) {
                        this.fields = {};
                        this.errors = {};
                        this.success = true;
                        // user should get redirected to the dashboard!    
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the loginController

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        if (Auth::attempt($validated)) {
            return response([
                'message' => trans('You have logged in successfully'),
                'status' => 200,
            ]);
        } else {
            return response([
                'message' => trans('Your login details are not correct'),
                'status' => 422,
                'errors' => ['failed' => trans('Your login details are not correct')],
            ]);
        }
```

This is API route

```
Route::post('/login', [ApiAuthLoginStore::class, 'store'])->name('api.login.store');
```

This is Web route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', [AuthLoginCreate::class, 'create'])->name('login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [AuthDashboardIndex::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: It seems you push your route `/dashboard` on your Vue-router, but the route is defined in Laravel? Have you actually defined the `/dashboard` route in Vue-router?

Comment: No I have no vue-router. Because I am new in Vue I have tried everything. I don't know how I can redirect a route from vue to laravel route and that is my problem

Comment: I suggest you move your `/api/login` route to a web route in laravel. The API routes use the api-middleware, which does not set cookies etcetera, meaning that a redirect to a web route will leave your user unauthenticated. Then, after successfull login, you could redirect in javascript using `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/dashboard"` for example.